# Database design regarding calculating an average score

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that looks something like this:
[image]

It is a database designed to keep track of players in a game. In the game, players have a score per event. Each player can have multiple scores per event. You can think of an event as a single day.

I want to keep track of their wins, losses, and skill. Skill is defined as their AVERAGE score of all their games played that day and the difference from the average from all players. IE, a player scores an average of 305, but the average of all players was 300, so his skill would be +5. Furthermore, the average of all players should be weighted only once, so a player who played 100 games versus a player who played 1 is not weighted more in the average.

My question is, what is the best way to accomplish this? The results from games are added one at a time, and I'm currently updating wins/losses using triggers. I'm unsure if trying to accomplish my average skill calculation using the DBMS would be wise, as between every insert it would have to calculate everything again. My program does about 1-2 inserts a second.

Retrieval speed from this database is VERY important, so I would much rather have inserts be slower than having to calculate this information every time I retrieve it if it is going to be slow in that method.

Comment: Do you need to recalculate *everything* on a new insert to get the retrieval performance you need? I imagine recalculating a single player's average is quick, and recalculating the overall average is quick, but then updating the skill for every player in an event is slow. Can you simply generate the skill on retrieval, its a single subtraction per row, rather than storing it and updating it continuously?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is in the middle.  I would build a stored procedure that runs every minute or every few minutes.  Then, on an insert, I would add that player's name to a queue, unless they are already present in this queue.  When the stored procedure runs, it pulls the names from the queue, and processes their data, removing them from the queue prior to starting the rollup (so if a record in inserted during the rollup, it forces another calculation to make sure nothing gets missed).  This improves performance, because you are eliminating many duplicates, but keeps a decent precision, since you run every few minutes, you are accurate to that time period.